# Is Edwin M. Stanton related to Elizabeth Cady Stanton?

Tags: united-states, 19th-century, american-civil-war, reconstruction

After reading part of an American history book over the weekend, I have a frankly dumb question.

Is suffragette [Elizabeth Cady Stanton](https://www.womenshistory.org/education-resources/biographies/elizabeth-cady-stanton) related at all to Reconstruction-Era Secretary of War [Edwin M. Stanton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Edwin_Stanton)?

For the slightly uninitiated in American history, Elizabeth Cady Stanton was one of the most famous American suffragettes of first-wave Feminism (probably only behind Susan B. Anthony). She's most known for writing the Declaration of Sentiments, which is a document which criticized the US Declaration of Independence's stance towards women. She was also a temperance activist and staunch abolitionist.

Edwin Stanton was the Secretary of War on Abraham Lincoln's Cabinet (the "Team of Rivals", as Doris Kearns Goodwin famously opined). He's probably most known for getting fired by President Andrew Johnson, which led directly to Johnson's impeachment trial, the first for a sitting president in American history.

AFAIK there are family tree applications that exist that could tell me their relationship, however I have neither the time nor the willpower to look for those. I also can't seem to find an answer to this quandary on any reputable online source.

Ironically, I found out that today was the anniversary of Elizabeth Cady Stanton's birth. How interesting.

Comment: How many generations back do you want to consider? Elizabeth Cady (daughter of judge Daniel Cady) married Henry B. Stanton (son of merchant Joseph Stanton), who does not appear to have been related to Edwin M. Stanton  within two generations.

Comment: I'll arbitrarily say four.

Comment: Www.genealogics.org apparently doesn't have anyone named Elizabeth Cady Stanton or Edwin M. Stanton.

Comment: @MAGolding: do you mean no background/family/related or no name? [Elizabeth Cady Stanton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elizabeth_Cady_Stanton)

Comment: [Documenting preliminary research will improve both the probability of an answer and the quality of the answer(s)](https://history.meta.stackexchange.com/a/785/26786) Quick google search turns up [geneology.com](https://www.genealogy.com/forum/surnames/topics/cady/2436/) which may help with further research, "https://www.genealogy.com/forum/surnames/topics/cady/2436/#:~:text=Robert%20Fulton%20was,the%20same%20time."

Comment: OTOH, they were both born in 1814/1815 - Edwin's family comes from the slaveholding south, Elizabeth's from Ohio.